# Window resize doesn't work when decreasing size in React useEffect

Tags: reactjs, window-resize, use-ref

I have the following useEffect call in React:

```
const containerRef = useRef(null);

useEffect(() => {
    function handleResize() {
        const {offsetWidth} = containerRef.current;
        setWidth(offsetWidth);
        console.log(width);
    }
    handleResize();
    window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
}, [containerRef, width]);
```

What I'm trying to do is get the width of a div that's wrapping a Victory Chart and pass that down to the chart so it can adjust it's aspect ratio to enable flexible width with a fixed height:

```
<div ref={containerRef}>
                            <VictoryChart theme={DataVizTheme} width={width} height={250} containerComponent={<VictoryContainer responsive={false} />}>
                                <VictoryAxis
                                    tickValues={[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]}
                                    tickFormat={["Mon 7", "Tue 8", "Wed 9", "Thu 10", "Fri 11", "Sat 12", "Sun 13"]}
                                />
                                <VictoryAxis
                                    dependentAxis
                                />
                                <VictoryStack>
                                    <VictoryArea interpolation="cardinal" padding="0" data={data} />
                                </VictoryStack>
                            </VictoryChart>
                        </div>
```

For some reason the "width" from the useEffect block only updates when the window size is increased. When it's decreased, the width stays the same.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

After spending more time evaluating my setup, I've figured out that the problem was at the  level, and not in the useEffect block. Adding a **minWidth of 100%** to the div made it update it's width when decreasing.